# error: 'Cannot read property 'divideBy' of undefined', L.Proj with esri.leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, esri-leaflet, proj4js

I am trying my first attempt at adding an (in-house published) ArcGIS basemap to a Leaflet based web application, using Proj4Leaflet and esri-leaflet.

Here is my js:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG: 2263', '+proj=lcc  +lat_1=40 +lat_2=41 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=984250 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs', {
 origin: [-120039300, 145506800],
 resolutions: [
  295.138888888889,
  217.013888888889,
  108.506944444444,
  55.5555555555556,
  27.7777777777778,
  13.8888888888889,
  6.94444444444444,
  3.47222222222222,
  1.73611111111111,
  0.8671875
]
});

var map = L.map('map',{
  crs: crs
  }).setView([40.721, -73.994], 5);

L.esri.tiledMapLayer('http://devserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/basemap/MapServer',{
    maxZoom: 9,
    minZoom: 0

}).addTo(map);
```

All of the projections parameters came from the properties of the source mxd of the tiled map service.  I tried integer-only values only because all the examples I found used integer values as well.
I was not able to find definitive documentation on how to define the properties for different projections in an L.Proj.CRDS object, so I tried following examples I found online.

This code results in a blank page, and I receive the error 'Cannot read property 'divideBy' of undefined'.  I am assuming something is missing or wrong in my reprojection parameters, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: perhaps you just need to replace the '12' in map.setView() to a value between 0 and 9?

Comment: good thought, but I still do not see any basemap rendered (although I am not seeing the error anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My co-worker led me to this very helpful website for getting spatial reference formats:
http://spatialreference.org/

I changed my crs variable to fit the format given by the site for EPGS:2263 (I did not need to use integers as I had thought).

```
 var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG: 2263', '+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.03333333333333 +lat_2=40.66666666666666 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000.0000000001 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=esri-ft +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs ', {
```

and added this property to the tiledMapLayer constructor:

```
  L.esri.tiledMapLayer('http://devserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/GISAPP_GAZETTEER/Basemap14AGrey/MapServer',{
    maxZoom: 9,
    minZoom: 0,
    **continuousWorld: true,**
    attribution: '***'
```

}).addTo(map);

Comment: glad to hear it.  another good one is http://epsg.io (for example: http://epsg.io/2263.js)